# Bulk insert in orientdb

Tags: orientdb

I have two different classes: `Record` and `Location`. `Record` has a `location` property that links to `Location` class.

I want to create a record with a new location in one statement pretty much like this:

```
insert into record content {location:{name:"EDR"}}
```

I was hoping this would create new location with name EDR and link it to location property of record but it throws this exception.

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OValidationException: The field 'record.location' has been declared as LINK but the value is not a record or a record-id
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
insert into record set location = (insert into location(name) values ("EDR"))
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also try this:

```
insert into Record set location = (insert into Location content {name:'EDR'})
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Seems the inner object is taken as MAP instead of document. However try to force the fact the inner object is a document and not a MAP (In OrientDB you can have both):

```
insert into record content {"@type":"d", "location":{"@type":"d", "name":"EDR"}}
```